# COM port number from Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to get the COM port number for a device through `DeviceInformation`? I can see COM port numbers when I look at them through Device Manager.

I just ran into a couple of devices that don't list the COM port number as part of the `Name` property. I plugged two of them in and there's no way to distinguish them from each other. Ideally, I'd like to see a COM port. Is there a different way to get that information?

```
string _serialSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection tempInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(_serialSelector);
    if (tempInfo.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var efefe in tempInfo)
        {
            if (efefe.Kind.Equals(DeviceInformationKind.DeviceInterface))
            {
                //efefe.Name                     
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done most of the job, then you will need to use your `efefe`'s id to get the `SerialDevice` object using [SerialDevice.FromIdAsync | fromIdAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.fromidasync.aspx).

Here is the demo:

```
string _serialSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var infos = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(_serialSelector);
foreach (var info in infos)
{
    var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(info.Id);
    if (serialDevice != null)
    {
        var port = serialDevice.PortName;
        Debug.WriteLine(port.ToString());
    }
}
```

And please don't forget to add `DeviceCapability` in manifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```